# Select unique records from different tables with minimum sum of values

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I have an SQLite database with 3 tables. Each of these tables have two columns: name and value such that all the tables have the same records (name) but different values. How do I select the records that are a part of least sum of values spanning across these tables such that the record names are unique?

Names: Steven, Jamie, Michael, Jordan, Gary

Values

(in the order of names)

Table 1: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Table 2: 2, 3, 1, 5, 6

Table 3: 9, 0, 2, 11, 3

The output should return (Steven, Michael, Jamie) because the sum of the values in this case would equal to 2 which would be the least possible.

Answer (score 1):

First, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, there is no correspondence between two tables based on position.  Instead, let me assume that each has a `name` column.

Second, SQL doesn't really do optimization, so you need to do this in a brute force way.  That is, generate all the combinations and then choose the minimum value.

That uses essentially a `cross join`:

```
select min(t1.value + t2.value + t3.value)
from table1 t1 cross join table2 t2 cross join table3 t3
where t1.name <> t2.name and t3.name not in (t1.name, t2.name);
```

Or, if you want the names:

```
select (t1.value + t2.value + t3.value), t1.name, t2.name, t3.name
from table1 t1 cross join table2 t2 cross join table3 t3
where t1.name <> t2.name and t3.name not in (t1.name, t2.name)
order by (t1.value + t2.value + t3.value)
limit 1
```

Comment: How would the where clause change if there were more than three tables?

Comment: @ExtremistEnigma . . . That would be a different question.  But, you would just add `t4.name not in (t1.name, t2.name, t3.name)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    SELECT T1.val,T2.val,T3.val FROM T1 , T2 , T3 
    WHERE T1.val <> T2.val AND T2.val <> T3.val AND T1.val <> T3.val
    GROUP BY T1.val,T2.val,T3.val,(T1.no + T2.no + T3.no)
    HAVING (T1.no + T2.no + T3.no) = 
    (SELECT MIN(T1.no)+MIN(T2.no)+MIN(T3.no)     FROM T1 , T2 , T3 
    WHERE T1.val <> T2.val AND T2.val <> T3.val AND T1.val <> T3.val)
```

If there are more then 3 tables just add tables after `FROM T1 , T2 , T3, T4,..TN`
And Add Comparision for not equality by adding this in where clause
`T1.val <> T4.val AND T2.val <> T4.val AND T3.val <>T4.val` for every table // this is added for T4